# Change <select> id on click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

There is a select option in search form and it has an id (e.g. `main_cat`).

Now I want that when I click on a link('a'), the id of `select` should be changed with `second_cat`.

> **Note** Give me solution with nesting div classes on jsFiddle, because `main_cat` id also used in another section on same page

Here is my sample code:

```
<div class="widget widget_vehicle_search">
    <div class="search-form-widget">

        <form id="wp-advanced-search" name="wp-advanced-search" class="wp-advanced-search" method="" action="">
            <div id="wpas-main_cat" class="wpas-main_cat wpas-generic-field  wpas-field">
                <div class="label-container">
                    <label for="main_cat">Select A Manufacturer:<i class="icon-help-circled-1 tooltip"></i></label>
                </div>

                <select id="main_cat" name="main_cat">
                    <option value="any">Any Manufacturer</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

> When Click on a link `main_cat` id changed with `second_cat`

Hope you understand my question

Comment: Sorry, but not totally clear )

Comment: Ids should be unique. I'd go with a class instead.

Comment: Also changing `id` attributes on the client is not a very good idea - they are designed to be static. If you want a new `select` element that holds different data, append it to the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that what you mean, but you could attach click event to anchor then on click change the `id` attribute of the select by the new one :

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('#main_cat').prop('id', 'second_cat');
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.log('Before : '+$('select').prop('id'));
  
  $('#main_cat').prop('id', 'second_cat');
  
  console.log('After : '+$('select').prop('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget widget_vehicle_search">
  <div class="search-form-widget">

    <form id="wp-advanced-search" name="wp-advanced-search" class="wp-advanced-search" method="" action="">
      <div id="wpas-main_cat" class="wpas-main_cat wpas-generic-field  wpas-field">
        <div class="label-container">
          <label for="main_cat">Select A Manufacturer:<i class="icon-help-circled-1 tooltip"></i></label>
        </div>

        <select id="main_cat" name="main_cat">
          <option value="any">Any Manufacturer</option>
        </select>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<a href='#'>change select id</select>
```

Comment: I really want this solution. But please can you give me code with nesting. e.g. `$('.widget_vehicle_search .search-form-widget #wpas-main_cat #main_cat').prop()` is this work?

Comment: Just `#main_cat` should works fine since `id` is unique, the provided selector will work but really no need for it use direct `id`.